# Detect if Windows Service is running of remote machine

Tags: windows, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check status of services that run in a remote computer using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335065/check-status-of-services-that-run-in-a-remote-computer-using-c-sharp)

Is it possible to check if a given windows service is running on a remote machine using C#?

This is assuming that I have the correct login credentials for that machine.

Comment: Is there an actual coding question here?

Comment: Log into machine, and check if service is running

Comment: I apologize , I forgot to mention that I want to do this programatically ( from C# )

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159498/net-classes-to-control-services-on-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162567.aspx), if you're using C# or VB.Net

Otherwise, "[SC](http://commandwindows.com/sc.htm)" is probably the best tool to use from a command line or .bat file.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

`sc \\<servername> query <servicename>`

Answer (score 1):

[psservice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542) from `pstools` does just this.

> PsService is a service viewer and controller for Windows. Like the SC
>   utility that's included in the Windows NT and Windows 2000 Resource
>   Kits, PsService displays the status, configuration, and dependencies
>   of a service, and allows you to start, stop, pause, resume and restart
>   them. Unlike the SC utility, PsService enables you to logon to a
>   remote system using a different account, for cases when the account
>   from which you run it doesn't have required permissions on the remote
>   system. PsService includes a unique service-search capability, which
>   identifies active instances of a service on your network. You would
>   use the search feature if you wanted to locate systems running DHCP
>   servers, for instance.